# Joomla 3.2 not working with template

Tags: joomla3.2

I have a joomla 3.2 site. Templates like eclipse,business,smartone are not working with my joomla site. Only 'home' shown, other menus are not shown in my page but default template works nice but i need to work with good template. Please help me!!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you provide the code that is failing? Without anything concrete to work with, it's hard to solve your issue. To learn more, take a look at [ask] and what we're [about]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Templates are managed by Joomla! in the same way as any other extension. But sometimes you may occasionally run into a situation where you cannot install a template in your Joomla 2.5 site with Upload Package File in the Extension Manager. And again and again you see this same message that the system could not find xml setup file (“JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file“). You have to use alternative template installation methods, for example, installation via FTP.

you can use use the following link to install it again manually:
https://www.gavick.com/documentation/general-questions/how-to-install-joomla-template-manually/